# Inventory Management: On hand quantity (vb.net or C#)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to migrate from Microsoft Access to an online asp.net website for my inventory management database.

In Microsoft Access I used Allen Browne's solution for inventory management: http://allenbrowne.com/appinventory.html and it works great for my needs but MS Access doesn't.

I have very basic knowledge in Visual Studio (I'm working mostly in Design Mode). Is there any similar solution, for Allen Browne function, that I can use to calculate on hand quantity of my inventory in visual studio?

Is there any way I can convert the vba function to C# or VB, or any way I can use it from the MS Access Module? (besides learning C# or VB from scratch and make my own function)

*Note: I haven't started the project yet so it does not matter if the solution is in C# or VB.net I don't know any of them so I will work mostly in design mode.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to be using access, why not learn VB for access?  Why complicate the whole project unnecessarily? Since VB for access is a relatively easy language and somewhat forgiving compared to others it's a good stepping stone to learning more complicated languages.

Comment: I'm not going to use access because, I feel like is very limited when used by multiple users at once. Plus the company already has a webhosting with a free sql db so I would prefer to use it as a website.

Comment: Not that I'm advocating access, I think SQL and maybe a PHP or other sever side language is better in some instances, but I I think saying Access limited with multiple users isn't accurate.  I've seen access used with multiple users plenty of times.  From 2 or 3, to in some case dozens of people at the same time. As long as it's been developed properly its an extremely cost effective tool for multiple users. Access also has the ability to use share-points sites and web applications development, making it very useful for web based applications.

Comment: Yes but I need to access the database over the internet, and as I sayd it would be easier to use the current webhosting rather than buy microsoft sharepoint. I tried access desktop database on dropbox but it doesn't work that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given sample VBA code should work very nearly the same in vb.net. You don’t have DAO, but in place I suggest using a datatable which is similar.

So vb.net is VERY similar to that of VBA code, and I often cut + paste such code between the two environments.

Before you attempt the above, you simply need to spend some time trying to work with a vb.net datatable. Try filling it with some rows, and then try looping over the data.

So a learning curve is required, but once you achieve the ability to write vb.net code that reads data, and how to execute a SQL update command, then the rest of example code will work and run much the same in VBA as it will in vb.net. This is especially the case since you are not talking about user interface code, but some VBA code (or now vb.net code) that runs in a standard code module.

If you have familiarly with Access, then likely the shortest learning curve is to adopt Visual Studio and vb.net. (and use web forms). This will allow you to drop buttons on a web page, and write code in vb.net which is VERY similar to VBA code.

Do keep in mind you need to determine what application and development stack your web hosting supports. If it is Linux based, or say only supports .net 2.0, then you need to adopt a set of web development tools that will work on the given hosting provider (or you have to change providers).

Comment: First, thank you all for taking the time to answer! I managed to design everything from my access form using only drag and drop (gridviews, buttons etc.) and some simple code. But because it's a inventory management database everything is based on that function to calculate on hand stock. I did as you said and copy and paste the function in a vb.net project now I'm stuck at that DAO thing. Can you please point me in the right direction I don't know how to select the current database. What should I replace the "Dim db As DAO.Database" and Recordset with? And db = CurrentDb() ?

Comment: You need to ask some new questions. And you need to add some tags such as asp.net and vb.net to the tags. The simple questions are how does one execute a update or action query using asp.net/vb.net. I also suggest you don't use Access for the data engine on the web site.  there is a ZILLION examples on stack overflow on how to execute a query. It is different then DAO.